Set database run config for parallel scripts
I am trying to run several postgresql scripts in a greenplum database in parallel using the run configuration features in pycharm. Base on the instructions from the pycharm website, I found that this can be done by creating several run configurations and then adding them to a compound configuration, which is what I have done.

The problem is that when I start executing this compound config it runs only a maximum of 3 scripts in parallel and begins execution of the remaining ones only after one of the initial three finished. So essentially I can parellarize only 3 scripts at a time. Is there any way of increasing this number from the pycharm settings or is this another issue all together?
I am using pycharm 2022.3

PyCharm’s compound configurations, while quite useful, rely on IntelliJ’s run/debug system. By default, this system often restricts the number of processes that can run concurrently, which explains why only three scripts are executing simultaneously. The remaining scripts begin only after one of the initial three finishes.

First, check that Greenplum is configured to support the number of concurrencies (max_connections parameter in the postgresql.conf file).
If that didn't fix it, since PyCharm doesn’t provide a setting to modify this in the UI, but its IntelliJ platform respects a specific system property for managing concurrencies, go to Help > Edit Custom VM Options and add -Didea.maximum.startup.concurrency=<desired number>.
If it still doesn't work, you can create a script to manage the parallel scripts. Use Python or Bash, you can use Python’s concurrent.futures module or Bash’s & operator for parallelization.


THe VM setting seems kind of inconsistent. When I first set it to 1000, it ran 10 scripts at once. Now it is back to running only 3 for some reason. Is there some other setting overriding it maybe?
